MacOS Monterey Disable Control+Left Click = Right Click
How do I stop my Mac from right-clicking when I hold control and left-click? This hotkey is extremely annoying when playing games where I have to hold control and left-click constantly.

Does this answer your question? Disable system-wide ctrl-click as right-click in Mavericks. Basically, you can't, it is hardcoded into the system.
